# Can I add a second hard drive to my Dell Inspiron i660s?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd, dell-inspiron

Is it possible to add a second hard drive?
I would like to have more space on my computer but I don't know if I can add a hard drive. In fact, I would like to add a solid state disk, but I haven't found anything on amazon. I don't know much about hardware and I need some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**

Stock configuration, no.

http://reviews.bestbuy.com/answers/3545/product/6877635/dell-inspiron-desktop-4gb-memory-500gb-hard-drive-questions-answers/questions.htm

---

**Long answer**

Fitting a regular 3.5" HDD will not be easily possible unless you remove the DVD drive and put an HDD in it's place using converter brackets:

http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Description=3.5%20to%205.25%20bay%20adapter&Submit=ENE

Fitting an SSD, physically, should be simple because you can put it anywhere you please with double-sided tape. Having enough ports and power connectors could be an issue.

The motherboard comes with 2 SATA data ports: one for HDD and one for DVD drive. If you don't need the DVD drive then disconnect it and connect your SSD, end of story.

But if it has a PCIe slot then you can buy an expansion card for more SATA ports

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16815124027

But you will need to make sure that there is an extra SATA power connector coming from your PSU:

https://wiki.installgentoo.com/images/2/22/15pin_sata.jpg

Or you can buy a converter:

http://www.pcdirectuk.com/content/images/thumbs/0000289_4pin_molex_to_sata_power_connector.jpeg